# Serial Gigabit Media Independent Interface (SGMII) - 1.25 Gbps vs 1 Gbps?

Tags: sgmii

What is the difference between 1.25 Gbps vs 1 Gbps SGMII signal data rate?

My understanding is that 1.25 Gbps is the raw data rate and 1 Gbps is the actual data rate (After removing the headers and all other information attached to the data)
Below screenshot is form this [document](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/gig_ethernet_pcs_pma/v16_1/pg047-gig-eth-pcs-pma.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few pages before the paragraph you asked about is this diagram:

[image]

In the transmit path, every 8 bits of data entering from the left is converted to a 10 bit line code by the 8B/10B encoder before it exits on the right to be serialized by the SERDES and sent on to the line (optical fiber or twisted pair) by the PMD (physical medium dependent) block.

So if you have 1 gigabit per second of data, you will produce 1.25 gigabits per second of serialized code symbols on the line.

The input to this block isn't strictly *raw* data since the data has added framing overhead added by the MAC layer before it reaches this point.

Comment: The SGMII uses 625 MHz as clock with double data rate. This means it sends 1250 Mbits/sec of data. And the hardware uses 8 bit / 10 bit encoding to maintain the DC balance of the line (a.k.a bit-stuffing), so 1250 Mbps x 8 / 10 = 1 Gbps.

Comment: @AananthCN, 1250 Gbaud doesn't mean 1250 Mbit/s of data. It's 1000 Mbit/s of data with 250 Mbit/s of coding overhead that doesn't convey any additional information, although it does contribute to signal balance and error detection.